# iOS PHPickerViewController does not provide Exif/Meta-Data

Tags: ios, swift, metadata, exif, phpickerviewcontroller

I am trying to read out some metadata from images which I fetched with the PHPickerViewController.

```
var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
self.phPicker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
if let picker = self.phPicker {
    self.phPicker?.delegate = self
    self.present(picker, animated: true) {
        self.phPicker = nil
    }
}
```

But the PHPickerResult.assetIdentifier to access those data is always nil.

```
extension ChatViewController: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        dismiss(animated: true) {
            if results.isEmpty {
                return
            }
            assert(results.first!.assetIdentifier != nil)  // fails
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is the correct configuration of the PHPickerViewController.

```
var config = PHPickerConfiguration()  // WRONG!
let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
```

According to documentation you have to use the PHPhotoLibrary.

> A PHPhotoLibrary provides access to the metadata and image data for
> the photos, videos and related content in the user's photo library,
> including content from the Camera Roll, iCloud Shared, Photo Stream,
> imported, and synced from iTunes.

So just use PHPhotoLibrary in the constructor and everything works fine.

```
var config = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: PHPhotoLibrary.shared())  // CORRECT!
let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
```